# Queue asynchronous task in Play! - correct way

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, akka, task-queue

I have a little Play! application(2.1, scala) which acts as a RESTful front-end for a Java library. This web app queues tasks for background processing using:

```
Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(Duration(0, SECONDS)) {
      new TaskWorker().run(batchId)
}
```

in `Tasks` controller.

The goal is to immediately start heavy processing by the Java library, but in the background.

In advent of Scala 2.10 and its [futures and promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html), will it make more sense to refactor the queuing to leverage this new API?

In general, I'm looking for a way to be able to perform background processing as currently implemented by [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) Ruby library, but perhaps having an in-process memory queue.(Redis-backed queue would be fine too).

Answer (score 1):

use Akka actor

```
case class BatchTask(id: Int)
class TaskActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case BatchTask(batchId) => new TaskWorker().run(batchId)
  }
}

val taskWorker = context.actorOf(Props[TaskActor])

taskWorker ! BatchTask(batchId1)
taskWorker ! BatchTask(batchId2)
taskWorker ! BatchTask(batchId3)
```